# Cakephp:How do i calculate the age given the date of birth

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Hie i want to print the name of a person after they enter their date of birth.How do i calculate their age in cakephp.

My date field name is referenced as follows

```
ApplicantsDetail.dob
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$then = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d", "1983/12/16");
$diff = $then->diff(new DateTime());
echo $diff->format("%y year %m month %d day\n");
```

Output:

> 28 year 6 month 12 day

Create a custom helper from that code and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any code specific to CakePHP - use date_diff()

Check out the doco at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php